# In JQuery, the button won't activate after reloading

Tags: jquery, button, prop

I have a really simple question.

I have a button on this page which when pushed, opens a portion of the page in a pop-up window. As is, if you push the button multiple times, it will open that many pages in that window, so what you get is a stream window on top of a stream window on top of a stream window.

I set the button to disabled when it's clicked, but the problem is it won't becomes active again when the entire page itself is refreshed.

What I'm asking for is either help in resetting the button to become active again on a page reload or alternatively, make it work on only one button click per page load/reload.

Here is the code.

```
 <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

$("#OpenStreamWindow").click(function () {
                    var streamHtml = document.getElementById("stream").innerHTML;
                    var newStreamWindow = window.open("", "My stream window", "width=480,height=302,scrollbars=1,resizable=1")
                    newStreamWindow.document.write("<html><head></head><body>" + streamHtml + "</body></html>")
                    $(this).prop('disabled',true)
                });
<input id="OpenStreamWindow" type="button" value="Open stream in new window" />
```

Comment: How are you refreshing the page? If you're reloading the entire page, nothing should be retained from a previous load unless you do it explicitly, e.g. using cookies.

Comment: Refreshing it with either F5 or the reload button at the top of the page.

Comment: if you refresh the window that contains the link. The disabled prop should be gone. Can you link us the page where this is happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/492mR/show

Comment: The site is not up, I'm working on it in Adobe Dreamweaver. What's happening is, I preview it in Firefox by opening the page there, and then it gives me these results.